# Affine Varieties

Tags: commutative-algebra, affine-varieties

I came across a task from an old exam I don't know how to solve. The task is the following. Let $V=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : x^4=y^4\}$. 
1) Find the irreducible Components of $V$.
2) What is the dimension of $V$? 
I struggle a lot with affine varieties actually, so any help is greatly appreciated. What I know is that $V=Z(x+iy)\cup Z(x-iy)\cup Z(x+y)\cup Z(x-y)$ and I think that a subset $A \subseteq k^n $ with a field $k$ is irreducible exactly when $I(A)$ is a prime ideal with $I(A)$ being the set of all polynomials that have every $a \in A$ as a root. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: The dimension of a irreducible affine variety $Z(I)$ for some ideal $I \subset k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is the transcendence degree of $\operatorname{Quot}(k[x_1, \dots, x_n] / I)$ over $k$. Does this sound familiar?

Comment: Yes, that sounds familiar. However I have no intuition whatsoever regarding this chapter, therefore I can hardly work on from there. As far as I remember, the transcendence degree was just the length of the transcendencebasis, which exists for Quotientrings, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

All of the ideals $x \pm y$ and $x \pm iy$ are prime. For example, $\mathbb C[x, y] / (x - y) \cong \mathbb C[t]$ via the isomorphism $x \mapsto t$ and $y \mapsto t$. This gives us (a).

For (b), we have the following chain of ideals,
$$
0 \subset (x^4 - y^4) \subset (x - y) \subset (x, y).
$$

Since the $\dim \mathbb C[x, y] = 2$, we have $1 \le \dim V \le 2$. The dimension of $V$ cannot be $2$, for otherwise we would have a chain of ideals in which each $\mathfrak p_i$ is prime,
$$
0 \subset (x^4 - y^4) \subset \mathfrak p_1 \subset \mathfrak p_2 \subset \mathfrak p_3.
$$

This would contradict the fact that $\dim \mathbb C[x, y] = 2$. We conclude that $\dim V = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I'm not that fast at seeing that this is an isomorphism, so I will need a bit to check that myself, is there some sort of trick you used to come up with that so fast or is it experience? For (b) I don't think we ever stated that if $V \subseteq k^n$ then the dimension has to be less or equal too. However it makes sense, since the primeideal chain can't be longer. Isn't the first chain you gave a chain of prime ideals as well? Wouldn't the dimension then be 4? Could you also explain a bit more why the 2nd chain has to have that form? I don't really see that yet.